# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")
authority = input("Authority level (1 or 2): ")
name = input("Name           : ")
surname = input("Surname        : ")
idnum = input("Identity Number: ")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userInfo(username TEXT, password TEXT, authority TEXT, name TEXT, "
          "surname TEXT, idnum TEXT)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO userInfo VALUES(username, password, authority, name, surname, idnum) "
          "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
          (username, password, authority, name, surname, idnum))

conn.commit()
```

There seems nothing wrong but it returns:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error

and users.db remains empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope.. I get it..

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO userInfo (username, password, authority, name, surname, idnum) "
```

VALUES is making this error..

I hate this when I post my question here (I post here atleast after thinking 1 hour about it) I immedietly find the answer...